# Network Sharing

Tags: release-loki, networking, sharing

I And My Friend Both Have eOS installed And We Want To Enable Network Sharing So We Can Access each other's files.
Since We Both Are New To eOS We Don't Know How To Do That Can Any One Please Explain to Me How To Enable Network Sharing. We Want To Share All Of Our Drives With Each Other.

Answer (score 1):

Oh for that you have to insall Samba by using this ***sudo apt-get install samba*** command from terminal Or you can open the app store and do a search for samba. Once install you should be able to right-click on a folder to share.

The other way is to change the permissions of the **Public** folder in your Home directory to 777(read,write,execute); I personally would not use the 2nd option but is an option. So once you do either of these you should be able to see each others folders/files by clicking on the "Entire Network" in the Network section within the file manager(pantheon-files).

**Please remember that you both need to be on the same network so see each others PCs/Laptops.** If you are not within the same network then you will have to use a service like dropbox or google drive.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple with eOS. All you have to do is to install `openssh-server` and `openssh-client`. OpenSSH stands for open source secure shell. So with OpenSSH you can even run terminals on remote machines and do cool things like the dark guys with hoods do.

So just do

```
$ sudo apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client
```

on both eOS machies. By default OpenSSH will work on port 22. If you want to tweak openssh-server configuration then the config file is at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html)) However for simple file sharing you can carry on with the default configuration.

Now all you need is to open Files tool of eOS and click "Connect to Server..." at the bottom of the left menu. Choose SSH at the "Type:" dropdown list, enter IP number of the remote server at "Server:", enter your friend's credentials ("User name:" and "Password:") and click "Connect".

For additional reading on OpenSSH read [this](https://darrynvt.wordpress.com/2012/02/20/openssh-server-and-client-a-complete-guide-ubuntu/).